# Как автоматически закрывать сессию после истечения заданного времени с момента старта?

Tags: sql, oracle

Xочу добится, чтобы сессии БД закрывались автоматически, если со времени старта прошло более 1 часа.

Как это можно сделать?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [how to kill active sessions oracle automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54518111) от участника [@Tigran Shahnazaryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7568814/tigran-shahnazaryan)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Moжно просто создать профиль и установить в нем тайм-аут подключения и/или неактивности. И назначть этот профиль пользователям по мере необходимости.

Из документации к [CREATE PROFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-PROFILE.html#GUID-ABC7AE4D-64A8-4EA9-857D-BEF7300B64C3):

> If a user exceeds the `CONNECT_TIME` or `IDLE_TIME` session resource limit, then the database rolls back the current transaction and ends the session. When the user process next issues a call, the database returns an error.
> [...]
> **CONNECT_TIME**
> Specify the total elapsed time limit for a session, expressed in minutes.
> **IDLE_TIME**
> Specify the permitted periods of continuous inactive time during a session, expressed in minutes. Long-running queries and other operations are not subject to this limit.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create profile timeLimited limit
    connect_time 1
    idle_time 3
/
alter user me profile timeLimited;
```

Подключится и выполнить какой-либо запрос, а черз минуту повторить запрос:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "ME"
SQL> select 1 from dual;

         1
----------
         1

SQL> /
select 1 from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02399: exceeded maximum connect time, you are being logged off
```

Или будет следующее сообщение об ошибке, после 3 минут неактивности:

```
ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again
```